# what is a good summary of each book of tanach?

Tags: tanach

What is the basic one line summary of each book in the Tanach? It would be very convenient. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 20):

`[Gen]` The world comes to be.
`[Exo]` A nation goes free,
`[Lev]` and learns about service divine.
`[Num]` They wander and gripe.
`[Deu]` For Canaan they're ripe;
`[Jos]` they conquer it and land assign.
`[Jug]` They sin and repent,
`[Sam]` a king they are sent,
`[Kng]` and others follow in his wake.
`[Jer]` They hear they'll be gone,
`[Ezk]` but will come back anon,
`[Isa]` for God will not e'er them forsake.
`[12P]` Twelve seers have their views.
`[Rut]` King Dave's of the Jews,
`[Psa]` and writes songs that praise and revere.
`[Job]` Job suffers in pain;
`[Pro]` the proverbs pertain
`[Ecc]` as do thoughts of why we are here.
`[Son]` A love poem for you;
`[Lam]` some elegies, too.
`[Dan]` A man works for Babylon's king.
`[Est]` An Agagite planned.
`[Ezr]` Go back to our land.
`[Chr]` A summary of everything!

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4984